# AES Encryption program do not work correctly on IDEs

Tags: java, encryption, ide, aes, encryption-symmetric

**Program**

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
public class AesCtr256 {

// sBox is pre-computed multiplicative inverse in GF(2^8) used in subBytes and keyExpansion [§5.1.1]
private static final int[] sBox = new int[] { 0x63, 0x7c, 0x77, 0x7b, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0xc5, 0x30, 0x01, 0x67, 0x2b, 0xfe, 0xd7, 0xab, 0x76, 0xca, 0x82, 0xc9, 0x7d, 0xfa, 0x59, 0x47, 0xf0, 0xad, 0xd4, 0xa2, 0xaf, 0x9c, 0xa4, 0x72, 0xc0, 0xb7, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x26, 0x36, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x34, 0xa5, 0xe5, 0xf1, 0x71, 0xd8, 0x31, 0x15, 0x04, 0xc7, 0x23, 0xc3, 0x18, 0x96, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x07, 0x12, 0x80, 0xe2, 0xeb, 0x27, 0xb2, 0x75, 0x09, 0x83, 0x2c, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0xa0, 0x52, 0x3b, 0xd6, 0xb3, 0x29, 0xe3, 0x2f, 0x84, 0x53, 0xd1, 0x00, 0xed, 0x20, 0xfc, 0xb1, 0x5b, 0x6a, 0xcb, 0xbe, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x58, 0xcf, 0xd0, 0xef, 0xaa, 0xfb, 0x43, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x85, 0x45, 0xf9, 0x02, 0x7f, 0x50, 0x3c, 0x9f, 0xa8, 0x51, 0xa3, 0x40, 0x8f, 0x92, 0x9d, 0x38, 0xf5, 0xbc, 0xb6, 0xda, 0x21, 0x10, 0xff, 0xf3, 0xd2, 0xcd, 0x0c, 0x13, 0xec, 0x5f, 0x97, 0x44, 0x17, 0xc4, 0xa7, 0x7e, 0x3d, 0x64, 0x5d, 0x19, 0x73, 0x60, 0x81, 0x4f, 0xdc, 0x22, 0x2a, 0x90, 0x88, 0x46, 0xee, 0xb8, 0x14, 0xde, 0x5e,
        0x0b, 0xdb, 0xe0, 0x32, 0x3a, 0x0a, 0x49, 0x06, 0x24, 0x5c, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xac, 0x62, 0x91, 0x95, 0xe4, 0x79, 0xe7, 0xc8, 0x37, 0x6d, 0x8d, 0xd5, 0x4e, 0xa9, 0x6c, 0x56, 0xf4, 0xea, 0x65, 0x7a, 0xae, 0x08, 0xba, 0x78, 0x25, 0x2e, 0x1c, 0xa6, 0xb4, 0xc6, 0xe8, 0xdd, 0x74, 0x1f, 0x4b, 0xbd, 0x8b, 0x8a, 0x70, 0x3e, 0xb5, 0x66, 0x48, 0x03, 0xf6, 0x0e, 0x61, 0x35, 0x57, 0xb9, 0x86, 0xc1, 0x1d, 0x9e, 0xe1, 0xf8, 0x98, 0x11, 0x69, 0xd9, 0x8e, 0x94, 0x9b, 0x1e, 0x87, 0xe9, 0xce, 0x55, 0x28, 0xdf, 0x8c, 0xa1, 0x89, 0x0d, 0xbf, 0xe6, 0x42, 0x68, 0x41, 0x99, 0x2d, 0x0f, 0xb0, 0x54, 0xbb, 0x16 };
// rCon is Round Constant used for the Key Expansion [1st col is 2^(r-1) in GF(2^8)] [§5.2]
private static final int[][] rCon = new int[][] { new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 0
        new int[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 1
        new int[] { 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 2
        new int[] { 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 3
        new int[] { 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 4
        new int[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 5
        new int[] { 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 6
        new int[] { 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 7
        new int[] { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 8
        new int[] { 0x1b, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }, // 9
        new int[] { 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }// 10
};
private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Security.setProperty("crypto.policy", "unlimited");
    final int maxKeySize = javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES");
    System.out.println("Max Key Size for AES : " + maxKeySize);

    final String data = "My Encrypted String";
    final String key = "3e6cf9b346544bbb46ec99e33a9e0bcc";
    final String encrypted = encrypt(data, key, 256);
    System.out.println("Encrypted string=" + encrypted);
    System.out.println();
    final String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key);
    System.out.println("Decrypted string=" + decrypted);
}

/**
 * AES Cipher function: encrypt 'input' state with Rijndael algorithm [§5.1]; applies Nr rounds (10/12/14) using key schedule w for 'add round key' stage.
 *
 * @param {number[]} input - 16-byte (128-bit) input state array.
 * @param {number[][]} w - Key schedule as 2D byte-array (Nr+1 x Nb bytes).
 * @returns {number[]} Encrypted output state array.
 */
private static int[] cipher(int[] input, int[][] w) {
    final int Nb = 4; // block size (in words): no of columns in state (fixed at 4 for AES)
    final int Nr = w.length / Nb - 1; // no of rounds: 10/12/14 for 128/192/256-bit keys

    int[][] state = new int[4][];// [[],[],[],[]]; // initialise 4xNb byte-array 'state' with input [§3.4]
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
        if (state[i % 4] == null) {
            state[i % 4] = new int[4];
        }
        state[i % 4][(int) Math.floor((double) i / 4)] = input[i];
    }

    state = addRoundKey(state, w, 0, Nb);

    for (int round = 1; round < Nr; round++) {
        state = subBytes(state, Nb);
        state = shiftRows(state, Nb);
        state = mixColumns(state, Nb);
        state = addRoundKey(state, w, round, Nb);
    }

    state = subBytes(state, Nb);
    state = shiftRows(state, Nb);
    state = addRoundKey(state, w, Nr, Nb);

    final int[] output = new int[4 * Nb]; // convert state to 1-d array before returning [§3.4]
    for (int i = 0; i < 4 * Nb; i++) {
        output[i] = state[i % 4][(int) Math.floor((double) i / 4)];
    }

    return output;
}

/**
 * Perform key expansion to generate a key schedule from a cipher key [§5.2].
 *
 * @param {number[]} key - Cipher key as 16/24/32-byte array.
 * @returns {number[][]} Expanded key schedule as 2D byte-array (Nr+1 x Nb bytes).
 */
private static int[][] keyExpansion(int[] key) {
    final int Nb = 4; // block size (in words): no of columns in state (fixed at 4 for AES)
    final int Nk = key.length / 4; // key length (in words): 4/6/8 for 128/192/256-bit keys
    final int Nr = Nk + 6; // no of rounds: 10/12/14 for 128/192/256-bit keys

    final int[][] w = new int[Nb * (Nr + 1)][Nb];
    int[] temp = new int[4];

    // initialise first Nk words of expanded key with cipher key
    for (int i = 0; i < Nk; i++) {
        final int[] r = new int[] { key[4 * i], key[4 * i + 1], key[4 * i + 2], key[4 * i + 3] };
        w[i] = r;
    }

    // expand the key into the remainder of the schedule
    for (int i = Nk; i < (Nb * (Nr + 1)); i++) {
        w[i] = new int[4];
        for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
            temp[t] = w[i - 1][t];
        }
        // each Nk'th word has extra transformation
        if (i % Nk == 0) {
            temp = subWord(rotWord(temp));
            for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
                temp[t] ^= rCon[i / Nk][t];
            }
        }
        // 256-bit key has subWord applied every 4th word
        else if (Nk > 6 && i % Nk == 4) {
            temp = subWord(temp);
        }
        // xor w[i] with w[i-1] and w[i-Nk]
        for (int t = 0; t < 4; t++) {
            w[i][t] = (w[i - Nk][t] ^ temp[t]);
        }
    }

    return w;
}

/**
 * Apply SBox to state S [§5.1.1]
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[][] subBytes(int[][] s, int Nb) {
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < Nb; c++) {
            s[r][c] = sBox[s[r][c]];
        }
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * Shift row r of state S left by r bytes [§5.1.2]
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[][] shiftRows(int[][] s, int Nb) {
    final int[] t = new int[4];
    for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            t[c] = s[r][(c + r) % Nb]; // shift into temp copy
        }
        // and copy back
        System.arraycopy(t, 0, s[r], 0, 4);
    } // note that this will work for Nb=4,5,6, but not 7,8 (always 4 for AES):
    return s; // see asmaes.sourceforge.net/rijndael/rijndaelImplementation.pdf
}

/**
 * Combine bytes of each col of state S [§5.1.3]
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[][] mixColumns(int[][] s, int Nb) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        final int[] a = new int[4]; // 'a' is a copy of the current column from 's'
        final int[] b = new int[4]; // 'b' is a•{02} in GF(2^8)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a[i] = s[i][c];
            b[i] = (s[i][c] & 0x80) > 0 ? (s[i][c] << 1 ^ 0x011b) : (s[i][c] << 1);
        }
        // a[n] ^ b[n] is a•{03} in GF(2^8)
        s[0][c] = (b[0] ^ a[1] ^ b[1] ^ a[2] ^ a[3]); // {02}•a0 + {03}•a1 + a2 + a3
        s[1][c] = (a[0] ^ b[1] ^ a[2] ^ b[2] ^ a[3]); // a0 • {02}•a1 + {03}•a2 + a3
        s[2][c] = (a[0] ^ a[1] ^ b[2] ^ a[3] ^ b[3]); // a0 + a1 + {02}•a2 + {03}•a3
        s[3][c] = (a[0] ^ b[0] ^ a[1] ^ a[2] ^ b[3]); // {03}•a0 + a1 + a2 + {02}•a3
    }
    return s;
}

/**
 * Xor Round Key into state S [§5.1.4]
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[][] addRoundKey(int[][] state, int[][] w, int rnd, int Nb) {
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < Nb; c++) {
            state[r][c] ^= w[rnd * 4 + c][r];
        }
    }
    return state;
}

/**
 * Apply SBox to 4-byte word w
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[] subWord(int[] w) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        w[i] = sBox[w[i]];
    }
    return w;
}

/**
 * Rotate 4-byte word w left by one byte
 *
 * @private
 */
private static int[] rotWord(int[] w) {
    final int tmp = w[0];
    System.arraycopy(w, 1, w, 0, 3);
    w[3] = tmp;
    return w;
}

public static String encrypt(String plaintext, String password, int nBits) throws Exception {

    final int blockSize = 16; // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES
    if (!(nBits == 128 || nBits == 192 || nBits == 256)) {
        return ""; // standard allows 128/192/256 bit keys
    }
    // note PHP (5) gives us plaintext and password in UTF8 encoding!
    password = UTF8Encode(password);
    plaintext = UTF8Encode(plaintext);
    final int nBytes = nBits / 8; // no bytes in key
    final int[] pwBytes = new int[nBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++) {
        pwBytes[i] = Float.isNaN(password.charAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charAt(i);
    }
    int[] key = cipher(pwBytes, keyExpansion(pwBytes));
    // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long
    final int bytesExpand = nBytes - 16;
    if (bytesExpand > 0) {
        final int keyOriginalLength = key.length;
        final int[] expandKey = new int[bytesExpand];
        final int[] endKey = new int[keyOriginalLength + bytesExpand];
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, expandKey, 0, bytesExpand);// initial expandKey
        System.arraycopy(key, 0, endKey, 0, key.length);// copy all from key to endKey
        System.arraycopy(expandKey, 0, endKey, key.length, expandKey.length);
        key = endKey;
    }
    final int[] counterBlock = new int[16];
    final long nonce = 1543699; // System.currentTimeMillis();
    final long nonceMs = nonce % 1000;
    final long nonceSec = (long) Math.floor(nonce / 1000);
    final long nonceRnd = 27096; // (long)Math.floor(Math.random() * 0xffff);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        counterBlock[i] = (int) ((nonceMs >>> i * 8) & 0xff);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        counterBlock[i + 2] = (int) ((nonceRnd >>> i * 8) & 0xff);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        counterBlock[i + 4] = (int) ((nonceSec >>> i * 8) & 0xff);
    }
    final StringBuilder ctrTxt = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        ctrTxt.append((char) counterBlock[i]);
    }
    // generate key schedule
    final int[][] keySchedule = keyExpansion(key);
    // separate ciphertext into blocks (skipping past initial 8 bytes)
    final int nBlocks = (int) Math.ceil((plaintext.length()) / (float) blockSize);
    final String[] ciphertxt = new String[nBlocks];
    final byte[][] bytearray = new byte[nBlocks + 1][];
    bytearray[0] = ctrTxt.toString().getBytes();
    for (int b = 0; b < nBlocks; b++) {
        // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
        // done in two stages for 32-bit ops: using two words allows us to go past 2^32 blocks (68GB)
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            counterBlock[15 - c] = (b >>> c * 8) & 0xff;
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            counterBlock[15 - c - 4] = b / 0x10000000 >>> c * 8; /* 0x100000000 */
        }
        final int[] cipherCntr = cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule);
        // block size is reduced on final block
        final int blockLength = (b < nBlocks - 1) ? blockSize : (plaintext.length() - 1) % blockSize + 1;
        final byte[] cipherByte = new byte[blockLength];
        for (int i = 0; i < blockLength; i++) { // -- xor plaintext with ciphered counter byte-by-byte --
            cipherByte[i] = (byte) (cipherCntr[i] ^ ord(substr(plaintext, b * blockSize + i, 1)));
        }
        ciphertxt[b] = new String(cipherByte);
        bytearray[b + 1] = cipherByte;
    }
    int bigArraySize = 0;
    for (final byte[] bytes : bytearray) {
        bigArraySize += bytes.length;
    }
    final byte[] bigArray = new byte[bigArraySize];
    copySmallArraysToBigArray(bytearray, bigArray);
    return Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(bigArray);
    // return new String(bigArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static void copySmallArraysToBigArray(byte[][] smallArrays, byte[] bigArray) {
    int currentOffset = 0;
    for (final byte[] currentArray : smallArrays) {
        System.arraycopy(currentArray, 0, bigArray, currentOffset, currentArray.length);
        currentOffset += currentArray.length;
    }
}

public static int ord(String s) {
    // return s.length() > 0 ? (s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)[0] & 0xff) : 0;
    return s.length() > 0 ? (s.getBytes()[0] & 0xff) : 0;
}

public static int ord(char c) {
    return c < 0x80 ? c : ord(Character.toString(c));
}

private static String substr(String string, int from, int to) {
    final String substring = string.substring(string.length() - Math.abs(from));
    if (from < 0 && to < 0) {
        if (Math.abs(from) > Math.abs(to)) {
            return substring.substring(substring.length() - Math.abs(to));
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
    else if (from >= 0 && to < 0) {
        final String s = string.substring(from);
        if (Math.abs(to) >= s.length()) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return s.substring(0, s.length() - Math.abs(to));
        }
    }
    else if (from < 0) {
        if (to >= substring.length()) {
            return substring;
        }
        return substring.substring(0, to);
    }
    else {
        final String s = string.substring(Math.abs(from));
        if (to >= s.length()) {
            return s;
        }
        else {
            return s.substring(0, Math.abs(to));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Decrypt a text encrypted by AES in counter mode of operation
 *
 * @param {string} ciphertext - Source text to be encrypted.
 * @param {string} password - Password to use to generate a key.
 * @param {number} nBits - Number of bits to be used in the key; 128 / 192 / 256.
 * @returns {string} Decrypted text
 * @example
 */
private static String decrypt(String ciphertext, String password) throws Exception {
    String plaintext = "";
    // try {
    final int blockSize = 16; // block size fixed at 16 bytes / 128 bits (Nb=4) for AES

    ciphertext = base64Decoder(ciphertext);
    password = UTF8Encode(password);

    // use AES to encrypt password (mirroring encrypt routine)

    final int nBytes = 256 / 8; // no bytes in key
    final int[] pwBytes = new int[nBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < nBytes; i++) {
        pwBytes[i] = Float.isNaN(password.charAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charAt(i);
    }

    int[] key = cipher(pwBytes, keyExpansion(pwBytes));
    // expand key to 16/24/32 bytes long
    final int bytesExpand = nBytes - 16;

    final int keyOriginalLength = key.length;
    final int[] expandKey = new int[bytesExpand];
    final int[] endKey = new int[keyOriginalLength + bytesExpand];
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, expandKey, 0, bytesExpand);// initial expandKey
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, endKey, 0, key.length);// copy all from key to endKey
    System.arraycopy(expandKey, 0, endKey, key.length, expandKey.length);
    key = endKey;

    // recover nonce from 1st 8 bytes of ciphertext
    final int[] counterBlock = new int[16];
    final String ctrTxt = ciphertext.substring(0, 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        counterBlock[i] = ctrTxt.charAt(i);
    }

    // generate key schedule
    final int[][] keySchedule = keyExpansion(key);

    // separate ciphertext into blocks (skipping past initial 8 bytes)
    final int nBlocks = (int) Math.ceil((ciphertext.length() - 8) / (float) blockSize);
    final String[] cipherArr = new String[nBlocks];
    for (int b = 0; b < nBlocks; b++) {
        final int start = 8 + b * blockSize;
        final int end = 8 + b * blockSize + blockSize;
        if (end >= ciphertext.length()) {
            cipherArr[b] = UTF8Encode(ciphertext.substring(start));
        }
        else {
            cipherArr[b] = UTF8Encode(ciphertext.substring(start, end));
        }
    }
    // ciphertext is now array of block-length strings, ³F.àiþ±wãì¿,ß°d
    // plaintext will get generated block-by-block into "³F.àiþ±wãì¿,ß°" array of block-length strings
    final String[] plaintxt = new String[cipherArr.length];
    // Expand CounterBlock
    for (int b = 0; b < nBlocks; b++) {
        // set counter (block #) in last 8 bytes of counter block (leaving nonce in 1st 8 bytes)
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
            counterBlock[15 - c] = (b >> c * 8) & 0xff;
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++)
        // counterBlock[15 - c - 4] = (b / 0x100000000 >>> c * 8);
        {
            counterBlock[15 - c - 4] = 0;
        }

        final int[] cipherCntr = cipher(counterBlock, keySchedule); // encrypt counter block
        final char[] plaintxtByte = new char[cipherArr[b].length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < cipherArr[b].length(); i++) {

            plaintxtByte[i] = (char) (cipherCntr[i] ^ cipherArr[b].charAt(i));
        }
        plaintxt[b] = String.copyValueOf(plaintxtByte);
    }

    // join array of blocks into single plaintext string
    plaintext = joinArray(plaintxt);// plaintxt.Join('');

    // join array of blocks into single plaintext string
    plaintext = UTF8Decode(plaintext);// decode from UTF8 back to Unicode multi-byte chars

    return plaintext;
}

private static String joinArray(Object[] source) {
    final StringBuilder dest = new StringBuilder();
    for (final Object o : source) {
        dest.append((String) o);
    }
    return dest.toString();
}

private static String UTF8Decode(String s) throws Exception {

    final byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        // Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, "the char must be in byte's range");
        utf8Bytes[i] = (byte) s.charAt(i);
    }

    return new String(utf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static String base64Decoder(String data) throws Exception {

    final byte[] b = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
    // byte[] b = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);
    return new String(b, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}

private static String UTF8Encode(String s) throws Exception {

    return new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
}
```

**Expected Output** *(It runs correctly with cmd)*

[image]

Actual output on IDEs (Intellij,Eclipse)

```
Max Key Size for AES : 2147483647
Encrypted string=wrsCw5hpBwYAAGNJ2u4oXMphxxzlyt+hHAm5tVc

Decrypted string=��\��ʶ����r?3�cd�^
```

JDK that I'm using

```
java version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.5+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: If I use UTF-8 encoding in the Eclipse console I can (almost) reproduce your gibberish output. If I change the encoding to ISO-8859-1 (or Cp1252) in the _Run Configurations, Common-tab_ I get the expected result. Changing the encoding in the console is however not a reliable solution, because it only works for ASCII characters, i.e. not for e.g. `§` or `€`. Probably there are one (or more) encoding problems in the code itself. These are difficult to isolate, because encoding/decoding and encryption/decryption (and possibly algorithm and mode) are not sufficiently separated in the code.

Comment: @Topaco As your suggestion , I tested my java program with `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1` VM Options and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: You are really fighting a tremendous battle against character encodings and bytes in this code. It's hard to see why you have methods `UTF8Decode` and `UTF8Encode`. UTF8Encode appears to be nothing more than a uniquely slow version of a String clone, but since Strings are immutable there is no reason to bother at all. UTF8Decode looks plain wrong, but again I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: `pwBytes[i] = Float.isNaN(password.charAt(i)) ? 0 : password.charAt(i);` For what possible reason could you be checking if a 16-bit unsigned integer is a NaN? `Float.isNaN(password.charAt(i))` is always false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place where the error is taking place is in the encrypt-method where you generate the initialization vector (necessary for AES CTR mode). The iv is placed at the beginning of the encrypted string/byte array in bytearray[0]. Just change the line from

```
bytearray[0] = ctrTxt.toString().getBytes();
```

to

```
bytearray[0] = ctrTxt.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

and your program is working within your IDE or on command line.

Comment: Nice catch. Fixes the problem at least for ASCII texts.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/encoding.html) your files (Status Bar) and the project (Settings | Editor | File Encodings) have.

Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into Help | [Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) file and restart IDE.

Also check that the console has Font set (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Font) which is capable to display all the glyphs.

Comment: The output is incorrect from encryption phase. Check encrypted string values. My class file was already in UTF-8 encoding.And I tested by changing console font , this didn't work too.